# Filter a PCAP file using tshark : show ip source>ip destination:info in a txt file

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I need a tshark command so i can create a txt file containing  Ipsource>Ipdestination:Info  in this order ! i tried this command
tshark -T fields -n -r "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tracecomplete.pcap" -E separator=, -e ip.src -e ip.dst > "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\walima22.txt"*

but i can't change the separator and show the infos

Answer (score 1):

There are generally 2 solutions for printing specific column data, one using column-specifiers and the other using fields, similar to what you have.

**Using column-specifiers:**

Standard specifiers as described by `tshark.exe -G column-formats`:

```
tshark.exe -n -r "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tracecomplete.pcap" -o "gui.column.format:\"Source\",\"%s\",\"Destination\",\"%d\",\"Info\",\"%i\""
```

... or using custom columns for those fields that are supported:

```
tshark.exe -n -r "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tracecomplete.pcap" -o "gui.column.format:\"Source\",\"%Cus:ip.src\",\"Destination\",\"%Cus:ip.dst\",\"Info\",\"%i\""
```

---

**Using Fields:**

```
tshark.exe -n -r "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tracecomplete.pcap" -T fields -E separator=, -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e _ws.col.Info
```

---

*but i can't change the separator*
You should be able to change it using the `-E` option.  Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more help with this option.